# HTML website - browser compatibility

Tags: html, cross-browser

I have some problems with designing a website and I have no idea how to solve them. The main problem is browser compatibility. Here is the HTML code, it also includes 2 css files and one javascript file which I won't post since they would probably take too much space.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Quote genrator</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="quotes">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
@import url(menu/menu_style.css);
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="page">
<a href="ch25.html"><IMG class="logo" SRC="images/logo2.png" height=70 alt="images/logo2.png"></a>
<br>

<ul id="menu">

<li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="#" title="About us">About us</a></li>

<li><a href="#" title="Disclaimer">Disclaimer</a></li>

<li><a href="#" title="Contact us">Contact us</a></li>

<li><a href="#" title="Submit a qoute">Submit a quote</a></li>
</ul>


<p class="margin big auto">How do you feel about this quote<br>
<span style="color:black"><script language="javascript" src="quotes.js" type="text/javascript"></script></span> </p>

<div style="top: 370; position: absolute; visibility: show;">
<span style="cursorointer"><a href="ChAcc.html"><IMG class="margin opacity" SRC="images/smf.png" height=70

alt="images/smf.png"></a></span>
</div>

<div style="top: 370; left: 150; position: absolute; visibility: show;">
<span style="cursorointer"><a href="ch25.html"><IMG class="margin opacity" SRC="images/saf.png" height=70

alt="images/saf.png"></a></span>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here are screenshots of my website:

1. firefox
   http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/5485/13162041.png
2. internet explorer:
   http://img861.imageshack.us/img861/8895/30286878.png

I would like the site to be seen in IE the same way as it is seen in FX but the problem is that IE doesn't detect javascript code, two images and positions #page (the white part) on the left side.
I have tried to solve this problem with DOCTYPE tags but can't seem to find the right one. Any suggestions?

Comment: The standards rendering mode is the first (and sometimes the only) step to reach the cross-browser compatibility. Try `<!doctype html>` at the beginning of your markup.

Answer (score 0):

give `margin:o auto;` to your `#page`, may be it will work for you

Comment: The value `auto` of `margin` property does not work in IE's quirks mode.

Comment: go through the link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742877/center-align-div-in-internet-explorer`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the image positions (IE bugs are just way too annoying to track), but the reason it is not detecting the JavaScript is right in front of you. Looks like you are accessing your web page from your local drive. In such a case, IE blocks JS code. Click on the yellow bar and select 'allow ...' or a similar message.